# In Dart, how to prevent the output from Process.run() from being truncated while using .stdout

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Dart Code:

```
class PingService {
  static Future pingHost() async {
    return await Process.run('ping', ['-c', '4', '-s', '100', 'google.com'])
        .then((value) {
      if (value.stdout.toString().isEmpty) print('Error: ${value.stderr}');
      print(value.stdout);
      var result = value.stdout;
      print(result);
      return value.stdout;
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('PingService e: $e');
    });
  }
```

To get the output in string format, `.stdout` is used, and the output i get looks like this:

```
I/flutter ( 4781): PING google.com (172.217.167.142) 100(128) bytes of data.
I/flutter ( 4781): 76 bytes from maa03s26-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 (truncated)
I/flutter ( 4781): 76 bytes from maa03s26-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 (truncated)
I/flutter ( 4781): 76 bytes from maa03s26-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 (truncated)
I/flutter ( 4781): 76 bytes from maa03s26-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.142): icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 (truncated)
I/flutter ( 4781):
I/flutter ( 4781): --- google.com ping statistics ---
I/flutter ( 4781): 4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
I/flutter ( 4781): rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 60.938/71.722/82.532/10.083 ms
```

The rtt for each ping is truncated which I need, Is there any way to get the full output from the Process?

Comment: Maybe relevant? https://askubuntu.com/questions/957081/prevent-ping-output-from-showing-truncated-instead-of-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the data size returned is smaller than the data size sent, it will always print [truncated] and you have sent 100(128) bytes of data.

when you send the request with data size smaller 50(78) bytes

```
PING google.com (142.250.182.238) 50(78) bytes of data.
58 bytes from bom07s29-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.182.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=112 time=292 ms
58 bytes from bom07s29-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.182.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=112 time=436 ms
58 bytes from bom07s29-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.182.238): icmp_seq=3 ttl=112 time=347 ms
58 bytes from bom07s29-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.182.238): icmp_seq=4 ttl=112 time=37.9 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 37.981/278.823/436.424/148.169 ms
```

it won't return truncated.